# Ubuntu 11.10 netbook remix and BeagleBoard-xM Rev C

Tags: ubuntu, beagleboard, omap

I have a BeagleBoard-XM rev C that I've been trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 netbook remix on, preinstalled for ARM OMAP4. I've [followed the instructions](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu) to the letter using setup_sdcard.sh.

It seems I'm able to boot the board now (more than I can say about 95% of the time...) but it simply comes up with a terminal saying

```
Ubuntu 11.10 omap tty1
omap login: _
```

It seems that it's waiting for me to login with something, and the keyboard is responsive... but I've never been given a chance to configure any users, and there are no default users documented. I've tried all the combinations I can think of... root/root, ubuntu/[blank], etc...

Does anyone know what's going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
login: ubuntu
password: temppwd
```